# Class loading error with Spring Boot and Hibernate 5

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-4.x, hibernate-5.x

I recently upgraded a Spring Boot based application from Hibernate 4 to Hibernate 5. Since then I observe a class loading problem. Obviously, the hibernate classes and my domain class get loaded by two different class loaders. This only happens if I launch the application with Spring DevTools and Hibernate 5. The combinations DevTools/Hibernate 4, mvn spring-boot:run/Hibernate 5 work.

The problem can be reproduced with the following simple spring boot app (the full eclipse project is available [here](http://1drv.ms/1KRVYUQ))

```
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long     id;
    private String   firstName;
    private String   lastName;

    public Employee() {  
    }

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return id + ": " + lastName + ", " + firstName;
    }
}

public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {

        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("problem.domain");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(new Properties() {
            {
                setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect");
                setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
                setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
            }
        });

        return sessionFactory;
    }
}

@Component
public class DatabaseInitializer implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Employee empl = new Employee("John", "Doe");
        session.persist(empl);
        tx.commit();
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootMain.class, args);
    }
}

pom.xml:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>swt6.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate5-problem</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
        <derby.version>10.12.1.1</derby.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Running this program with Spring DevTools results in the following error:

```
2016-02-15 18:30:48.315  INFO 13828 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@55ad1b60'
2016-02-15 18:30:48.509  INFO 13828 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2016-02-15 18:30:48.536  INFO 13828 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-02-15 18:30:48.582 ERROR 13828 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.p.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl        : HHH000122: IllegalArgumentException in class: problem.domain.Employee, getter method of property: id
2016-02-15 18:30:48.583 ERROR 13828 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:800) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:787) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:777) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at problem.main.SpringBootMain.main(SpringBootMain.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of problem.domain.Employee.id
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl.get(GetterMethodImpl.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:223) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4633) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4344) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:226) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:499) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:778) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:751) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:756) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:338) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy56.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at problem.main.DatabaseInitializer.run(DatabaseInitializer.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:797) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl.get(GetterMethodImpl.java:41) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    ... 29 common frames omitted

2016-02-15 18:30:48.585  INFO 13828 --- [  restartedMain] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/D:/P20058/Documents/FH/Lehre/SWT6U/Uebungen/SpringWeb/hibernate5-problem/target/classes/]
2016-02-15 18:30:48.585  INFO 13828 --- [  restartedMain] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enable debug logging (start with --debug)


2016-02-15 18:30:48.585  INFO 13828 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@63e38bca: startup date [Mon Feb 15 18:30:46 CET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-02-15 18:30:48.587  INFO 13828 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2016-02-15 18:30:48.587  INFO 13828 --- [  restartedMain] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed drop of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2016-02-15 18:30:48.604  INFO 13828 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-02-15 18:30:48.604  INFO 13828 --- [  restartedMain] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed drop of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an open issue for supporting Hibernate 5 with Spring Boot [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2763).

In your example, there are two classloaders :

1. The system classloader
2. Spring Boot DevTools classloader, supporting the restart feature

The default implement of Hibernate ClassLoaderService resolve classes by first looking in his own classloader, and then the spring classloader.

Your class are loaded by spring (with the restart classloader), given to hibernate through the persistent-unit, but hibernate reload this class with his ClassLoaderService, and find it in his own classloader (the system cl). There are two classes loaded, and the consequence is the error you saw.

Spring can be configured to load hibernate in the restart classloader, but i didn't success to isolate a set of libraries : adding only hibernate-* fail with errors from spring-orm or a EntityManager not visible from the proxybuilder.

A working workaround (but really ugly!) : add in `META-INF/spring-devtools.properties`

```
restart.include.all=.*
```

I suppose there is a better solution than this one

Comment: could you please explain what that does? @Jérémie B

Comment: This is a proxy issue for many issues with the same root cause (`RestartClassLoader`). In my case the exception was `IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field MyEntity.id to MyEntity`. The same was reported by someone else at https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14553.